# using for loop in google charts with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Im working with Google charts, and I want to compare two values for example sales and expenses.  I'm using `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` method from Google charts, but I want to fetch values from database and show the corresponding values in the graph.

My sample code is

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['', '<%= request.getParameter("searchKey") %>', '<%= request.getParameter("competitor") %>'],
       ['<%=created_at[0]%>', <%=sentimentStats[0]%>, <%=sentimentStats1[0]%>],
       ['<%=created_at[1]%>', <%=sentimentStats[1]%>, <%=sentimentStats1[1]%>]

     ]);
}
```

I'm hardcoding values like this

```
['<%=created_at[0]%>', <%=sentimentStats[0]%>, <%=sentimentStats1[0]%>],
['<%=created_at[1]%>', <%=sentimentStats[1]%>, <%=sentimentStats1[1]%>]
```

Instead, I want to use it with for loop could you please help me.